# How to get handle on Old Value in Knockout using CoffeeScript

Tags: knockout.js, coffeescript

I am using Knockout in conjunction with CoffeeScript. I have a variable called `SalesStage.ID` which is an observable. I need get the old value, `oldVal`, how do I get it?

This is what I tried:

```
this.data.SalesStage.ID().subscribeChanged((newVal, oldVal)=> 
    console.log (oldVal) console.log(newVal))
```

And this is the following error:

> cannot call method subscribeChanged of null.

Any ideas and suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with the coffeescript syntax, so I'll write it in javascript, but wouldn't it be `this.data.SalesStage.ID.subscribe(function (oldValue) { console.log(oldValue); }, null, 'beforeChange');`? You can read more about it on the [KnockoutJS documentation page on Observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html).

Comment: @Robert, I agree with your solution in the comment, can you put this as an answer instead.

Answer (score 1):

In plain javascript you could subscribe to the old value when the value changes with the following code:

```
this.data.SalesStage.ID.subscribe(function (oldValue) { 
    console.log(oldValue); 
}, null, 'beforeChange');
```

You can read more about it on the [KnockoutJS documentation page on Observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html).